# JSON nodes Manipulation in JSONArray

Tags: java, json

I have a JSONArray which has multiple objects. I need help with implementation so that all the nodes containing **givenName : Carlos** must come on top in ordering.

```
    {
       "personList":   [
            {
                "givenName": "Jim",
                "formattedName": "jimJackson",
                "familyName": null,
                "middleName": "none",
                "honorificPrefix": "mr",
                "honorificSuffix": "none"
            },
            {
                "givenName": "john",
                "formattedName": "johnLasher",
                "familyName": null,
                "middleName": "none",
                "honorificPrefix": "mr",
                "honorificSuffix": "none"
            },
            {
                "givenName": "carlos1",
                "formattedName": "carlosAddner",
                "familyName": null,
                "middleName": "none",
                "honorifiPrefix": "mr",
                "honorificSuffix": "none"
            },
            {
                "givenName": "lisa",
                "formattedName": "lisaRay",
                "familyName": null,
                "middleName": "none",
                "honorificPrefix": "mrs",
                "honorificSuffix": "none"
            },
            {
                "givenName": "carlos2",
                "formattedName": "bradshawLion",
                "familyName": null,
                "middleName": "none",
                "honorificPrefix": "mr",
                "honorificSuffix": "none"
            },
            {
                "givenName": "phill",
                "formattedName": "phillKane",
                "familyName": null,
                "middleName": "none",
                "honorificPrefix": "mr",
                "honorificSuffix": "none"
            },
            {
                "givenName": "carlos3",
                "formattedName": "gabrielMoosa",
                "familyName": null,
                "middleName": "none",
                "honorificPrefix": "mr",
                "honorificSuffix": "none"
            } 
  ]
}
```

Code Snippet to show all nodes on Output

```
JSONArray jsonArray= (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("personList");

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(jsonArray.get(i));


}
```

I was thinking of creating a new JSONArray object and copy node which contains Carlos. Issues -

1. How to copy a particular node to New JSONArray?
2. I know JSONArray are not ordered, but Can I sort these nodes with
   particular key/value?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Map(String,Object) first and add all the JSON objects to the Map.

What I normally do is create a Model from the JSON object. For instance create a Person object and parse the JSON array to a List(Person).

In your case you could create a Map(String, Person), with the key as givenName. Then you can do what you want with the Collection: sort it, loop through it, create a Comparator etc.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class

```
class BO{
 String givenName;
 String familyName;
 String formattedName;
 String middleName;
 String honorificPrefix;
 String honorificSuffix;
}
```

You can use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library (or any other) to parse the json object into java object.
Once you have java object for each json object, make a collection of them.

Make an implementation of [comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface and you can compare the object according to your need.